# Why is this shorter include if returning empty but normal doesnt

Tags: php

Normal:

```
if($pages){
   include('public/pages/'.$pages->page.'.php');
}else include('public/pages/errors/404.php');
```

Shorten:

```
include('public/pages/' . ($pages) ? $pages->page : "errors/404" . '.php');
```

Why does this shorten way returns empty always but normal one works fine?
Can I only use echo with short `if(){}else{}` or what? Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: So just remove () for if?

Comment: No, _add_ proper (...) so that you append `.php` to the result of the expression afterwards, and not only to the second half of it.

Comment: enclose your ternary statement with () ? - ( ($pages) ? $pages->page : "errors/404" ) ?? So that the strings combine properly.

Comment: Okay but I have a question, I removed () and it works like it should:

include('public/pages/' . $pages ? $pages->page : "errors/404" . '.php');

Is it bad?

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"shorter `if`"*. The [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) is an operator, [`if` is a control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) (a statement). Operators and statements are different concepts, with different purposes in a program. They cannot be interchanged.

Comment: Read about [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). String concatenation (`.`) has higher precedence than the ternary operator (`?:`) and the expression does not evaluate as you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't adding `".php"` if the condition is true.

Change it to:

```
include('public/pages/' . ($pages ? $pages->page : "errors/404") . '.php');
```

Note how I added a second pair of parenthesis. ".php" is now added to whatever the ternary returns instead of being added directly to the false expression.

Without proper parenthesis what you are really comparing is `('public/pages/' . $pages)` and returning for true: `$pages->page` and for false `"errors/404" . '.php'` which is obviously wrong.

Comment: I would do it this way: `include('public/pages/' . (($pages) ? $pages->page : "errors/404") . '.php');`

Comment: I just removed () and it works fine is it bad? 
include('public/pages/' . $pages ? $pages->page : "errors/404" . '.php');

Comment: @StupidKid not really, ternary operator has lower priority than concatenation "."

Comment: As shown [in the PHP operator precenece list](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: I will accept your answer but just tell me difference between using your way and without ()? @Dragin

Comment: As others has mentioned - check operators priority. Without () you are comparing whole `'public/pages/' . $pages`, not only `$pages`.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php